# Regex while Replacing but IGNORE Within { } tags or inside Parentheses

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I've been doing regex for a few years now but having trouble with this one.

I am using a string like

```
$text_body = preg_replace("/[^\{].*?(FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|PHONE|EMAIL).*?[^\}]+/is", "{VARIABLETHISPARTISFINE}", $text_body);
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to have it Search and Replace ALL INSTANCES OF FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|PHONE|EMAIL, ETC Whatever I want, but I want it to SPECFICIALLY IGNORE ANYTHING THAT's INSIDE OF A { } or ( ).

How do I do this please?

Comment: Could there be `{nested {brackets} or (parentheses)}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a known [SKIP-FAIL trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). If you do not have nested parentheses nor braces, you can use

```
/(
  \([^()]*\) # Match (...) like substrings
 |
  {[^{}]*}   # Match {...} like substrings
)
(*SKIP)(*F)  # Ignore the texts matched
|
(?:FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|PHONE|EMAIL)/x
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO8zA5/1)

If you want to ignore the words like `PHONE`, `EMAIL` inside nested, balanced parentheses and braces, use a regex based on subroutines:

```
/(?:
 (\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\)) # Match (..(.)) like substrings
 |
 ({(?>[^{}]|(?2))*})   # Match {{.}..} like substrings
)
(*SKIP)(*F)  # Ignore the texts matched
|
(?:FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|PHONE|EMAIL)/x
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP6oJ7/1)

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0bvHJX):

```
$re = "/(?:
 (\\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\\)) # Match (..(.)) like substrings
 |
 ({(?>[^{}]|(?2))*})   # Match {{.}..} like substrings
)
(*SKIP)(*F)  # Ignore the texts matched
|
(?:FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|PHONE|EMAIL)/x"; 
$str = "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME PHONE EMAIL {FIRSTNAME LASTNAME PHONE EMAIL{FIRSTNAME LASTNAME PHONE EMAIL }FIRSTNAME LASTNAME PHONE EMAIL }"; 
$n = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
echo $n;
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much Brother!! Very much appreciate your assistance, it works like a charm!! You rock Wiktor~ Let me know if there's anything I can do for you mate! Have a great day!

Comment: Will do! I just enforced it into my script and I see ONE small problem. If the   MATCH Word is found INSIDE of an existing LARGER word, for instance the letter "A" is found in the word regarding... it will output Reg{a}rding. I need it to only match EXACT words (not matches inside larger words.. another example the... thesaurus will get replaced with {the}saurus.... Where to add \s \s to front and end, or better to match with ^ and $ ?  Thanks in advance! Almost works perfect!! Does it's job just a little too general.

Comment: Use word boundaries `\b`: `\b(?:FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|PHONE|EMAIL)\b`

Comment: great thank you. got it running using white space boundaries but will change to word boundaries as it's a better idea! Thanks again Wiktor!